# border-radius in Chrome bug?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit, border

I have a problem with the border-radius in chrome
    this is my code:

```
img{
border-radius: 24px;
border: 2px solid #c7c7c7;                 
-moz-border-radius:24px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 24px;
}
```

On mozzila it works fine, but on chrome it looks funny...
On mozzila I can see a circle bordering my image, but on chrome the circle crops the borders and all i can see are straight line

a screenshot: http://postimage.org/image/27turq0mc/

can you help?

Comment: can you give an example http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/Q55C8/5/

Comment: I can't see the image...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is probably a chrome bug. A solution could be to wrap the `img` with a `div` and make the following css:

```
img{                
    -moz-border-radius:24px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 24px;
    border-radius: 24px;
    display:block;
}
div {
    border: 2px solid #c7c7c7; 
    border-radius: 24px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 24px;
    width:40px; /* the width of image */
    height:40px; /* the height of image */
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/EnmMp/1/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the solution provided by:

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-rounded-image-with-jquery

fixed the problem.

First it shows the solution using only CSS3 & HTML and then it presents the solution using JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it on a background image instead of on a html img element, as some img elements dont work with border radius (yet i gueass).

```
div.something{
background-image:url(something.png);
border-radius: 24px;
border: 2px solid #c7c7c7;
border-radius: 24px;
}
```

Comment: my images are generated by a php function...
and i have to work on the img as it is...

Comment: then you have a problem as the border is not alowed to cut a image element, but you could try to dynamicaly changing the background with php, and as im not a php guy here is a link http://drupal.org/node/98246

Comment: Using a background-image instead is not a workaround for this bug. The bug still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

instead of just the below code  for border

```
-moz-border-radius: 2px 2px 15px 15px;
```

For the radius to be applied clockwise starting from top-left, you can’t do that for Webkit at the moment. So you have to write it out long hand like:

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
```