# Style of the image is ignored when printed

Tags: html, css, image

The below image looks circular(as intended) on the screen. When printed it ignores the style and looks squared.

```
<img src="@(helper.StaticUrl + helper.Detail.Picture)" width="158" height="158" alt="" style="border:5px solid rgba(255,255,255,1.0); border-radius:100px;" />
```

How can I force it to have style values on printing as well?

Comment: Ain't we talking about IE here?

Comment: Does it make difference? Looks OK on all browsers. But not on paper.

Comment: Of course it does. What happens when you print from Chrome/Firefox?

Comment: Do you have a print stylesheet?

Comment: No I don't have. I cannot use @media thing.

Comment: @raina77ow Hold on let me check

Comment: Meanwhile check [this link](http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=2140).

Comment: Firefox made it look as expected. Chrome not either.

Comment: Is [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739708/border-radius-in-chrome-bug) applicable in your case?

Comment: I must be doing sth wrong. Two different circular, one still gets squared. Still trying to make it happen.